# tar command junkfiles how to find it out

Tags: disk-usage, tar

Running `tar -cvzf mntpointtoexternaldrive\myarchive.tar.gz /home/user`
eats alls free space on /home/user disk  (same as system disk) and stop with error no left space message. Where can i find the junk tar files to free up space and how to backup home dir from commandline?

Comment: Can usually be deleted : These two hidden directories → `/home/name/{ .cache/, .thumbnails/ }`

Answer (score 0):

If you have extract the tar file to home. You can run

```
du -ah --max-depth=1 ~/
```

to figure out which fold take most space.

Or check the tar file with out extract tar.

```
tar vtf your.tar.gz
```

If you want to backup your home dir, you can `exclude` some path like this:

```
tar --exclude /path -zcvf file.tar.gz /etc /home
```